# Screen Manage Multi Session

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've a session named "super", and in this session I've used 3 times the command `ctrl-a c`, so that I've 4 shells that run in "super" session.

**My question is:** if I connect via ssh to my machine, how can log directly in "3 bash" shell (for example)?

I would launch different commands for different `# bash`.

**EXTRA:** someone knows how can i print directly in Terminal the list of all shells created in "super" session? (whithout display it with `screen -X windowlist`, that can't be saved in text file).

Comment: did you try anything yet ?

Comment: For the EXTRA question you can use tmux, which by default have a list of opened session on the statusbar.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, I don't try anything except `screen -X windowlist`: this command open a display table... I would like save this output inside a file, so I can menage this output for reach my goal.

Comment: @Atropo, unfortunately tmux is not installed on the machine, and I can't install since I'm not the amchine's Admin.